# How to extend Number in TypeScript by adding a function similar to ++

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to extend `Number` with a `plusPlus2` function that will increment the number by 2.

The problem is that I don't know how to assign the result back to the number in the extension function. Something like:

```
Number.prototype.plusPlus2 = function() {
    this = this + 2;
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
x = 1;
x.plusPlus2(); // expect x to be 3
```

Comment: Please don't monkey-patch built-in types: it adds extra complexity to maintenance and debugging.

Comment: I don't understand why `x += 2` is insufficient

Comment: @tic I used this as an example. My specific case is different. I need an operator that increments by 1 and when it gets to threshold it starts again from 0. I want to use it to control the index in an array that is used as a circular storage for a list of items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives (numbers, strings, booleans) are immutable in javascript.

So anytime you change a primitive, you need to assign it to another variable (or even reassign it to itself).

That being said, you cannot do what you propose, you need to return a new value, containing the value you want, let's say:

```
Number.prototype.plusplus2 = function() { 
    return this + 2;
}
```

And then reassign it:

```
let x = 5;
x = x.plusplus2();
```

Then, you may be wondering: **how `x++` works?**

And the answer is, `x++` is a syntax sugar for `x = x + 1`, meaning that, in fact, you are not changing `x`, but instead, adding 1 to `x` and reassigning it to itself.

Comment: "x++ is a syntax sugar for x = x + 1" --- that surely is not true. `var v = '0';` and then try to `++` vs `+1` it. I find claiming something "syntactic sugar" is counter-productive, given almost always there are nuances.

Comment: I think this is a naive question but I'll ask anyways, is there a way to add "syntax sugar" to TS inside a project?

Comment: Not really. In other languages, like Ruby, C, you can create your own syntax sugars, like "i+++", for example, as the "+++" is considered a method. In javascript (or typescript, which is a [superset of javascript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)), the "i++" is not considered a method, instead, it's part of the language (like "function", "while", "for" keywords), which is defined in the language grammar itself

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. That has various reasons:

1) `this` is read only, as you don't expect it to change during the execution of a method.

2) What you access with `this` is a Number object that wraps the primitive number. It gets thrown away after the call. So even if you *could* change the internal value property containing the number, the value of `x` won't change.

```
 Number.prototype.example = function() { this.stuff = "you see" };
 let x = 1; // primitive
 x.example(); // wrapped object
 // wrapped object gets thrown away
 console.log(x.stuff); // undefined, another wrapped object
```

3) Numbers are immutable and primitive. You can write a new number into `x`, but you can't turn all 1s into 3s.

---

You could create a new number, but then you have the problem that you have to write that number into `x`.

```
 Number.prototype.plus2 = function() { return this + 2 };
 let x = 1;
 x = x.plus2();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Number.prototype.plus2 = function() {
    return this + 2
}

let a = 2
console.log(a.plus2())
```

Comment: Generally, an answer should have a bit more explanation to it beyond just code - it needs to be useful to others in the future.